# Is it possible to create an external shared link under the group's name?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to know, If it is possible to create an external shared link under the group's name using Dropbox API in python. Currently, I'm generating links under my account

```
user = 'dbmid:CODE'
dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(ACCESS TOKEN)
download_url = dbx.as_user(user).sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings(dropbox_path).url[:-1] + '1'
```

But those links are associated to my name. So it is possible to create it under Group's name, so on this website(https://www.dropbox.com/team/admin/external_sharing?role=work) it would show "Shared by : GROUP NAME" and not my Name?
Group == Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to create a shared link associated with a group instead of an account, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.